# Edit external links location in PDF and save the file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I just want to open a pdf file, replace the external links target than save the file.

The links text or image remains unchanged, just the location.

I've been looking at pdftk, combine_pdf but I couldn't figure it out how to do it or if it's even possible.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

I prefer open-source solutions.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could do this with the Javascript API in Adobe Acrobat. Not an open source tool, but well...

Comment: Thanks but Adobe SDK costs $25,000 + $5000/year , so...

Comment: You don't need the Adobe SDK for that - it's possible to run the standard Adobe Acrobat and execute scripting commands using that...

Comment: Yea, but I need to do this in batches and from server side.

Comment: OK, well, any library that supports modifying low-level PDF objects (often referred to as "COS" objects) would allow you to modify the URLs in the way you need. Because you don't want to change the visual appearance of the links, but only the targets, you just need a library that can modify basic PDF objects. So look for something that can do that, and can modify an existing file (not just read or write but both).

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find anything for ruby, most of them are generators or converters. I just found an implmentation of iText on ruby using Rjb, I'll give that a try. It's strange that there are no pdf editing gems out there.

Comment: If you know the structure of the PDF files and what you're looking for, you can use `combine_pdf` to access the raw data. All the raw PDF objects are available as `pdf.objects` and you can look through the array into each of the Hash objects... there are also separate specialty objects, such as the `pdf.info` and `pdf.forms_data` as well as an unexposed objects `pdf.instance_variable_get :@names` and `pdf.instance_variable_get :@outlines` (see [the source code](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf/blob/615ae96e0bf16b37154c0cd17c8fcd01b859fbb2/lib/combine_pdf/pdf_public.rb#L86-L109)).